# Call to undefined function hash_equals()

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error

Magento version 1.9.3.6

Full Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash_equals() in /var/www/vhosts/lassco/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php on line 103
```

This occurs when I enter my admin details to login to the magento cms

I've checked my functions.php file and it seems to be patched correctly with the following code at the end of the file.

```
if (!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    /**
     * Compares two strings using the same time whether they're equal or not.
     * A difference in length will leak
     *
     * @param string $known_string
     * @param string $user_string
     * @return boolean Returns true when the two strings are equal, false otherwise.
     */
    function hash_equals($known_string, $user_string)
    {
        $result = 0;

        if (!is_string($known_string)) {
            trigger_error("hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if (!is_string($user_string)) {
            trigger_error("hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if (strlen($known_string) != strlen($user_string)) {
            return false;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($known_string); $i++) {
            $result |= (ord($known_string[$i]) ^ ord($user_string[$i]));
        }

        return 0 === $result;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`hash_equals` are not available on PHP versions prior to 5.6

Comment: The patch in the functions.php file covers that issue

Answer (score 0):

This library has a bug.

Mage.php line 51 uses

```
include_once "Mage/Core/functions.php";
```

When it should be

```
include_once "app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php";
```

This is only the case for when trying to login on the admin page though

A fix would be great